# Is it correct to return IndexesSeq instead of Array if an immutable array is needed in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, immutability, scala-collections

A function of mine produces an array - an ordered, contiguously numbered set of records. But as far as I know Scala Array is a mutable collection, while functional approach suggests it would make more sense to return an immutable collection in a general case. So I just call `Array.toIndexedSeq` to return an `IndexedSeq` instead of `Array`. Can this be considered a correct thing to do? Doesn't it introduce any inobvious behaviour which can influence the function and the result usage and be probably considered undesirable? Are there any better practices for the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this be considered a correct thing to do?

Yes.

> Doesn't it introduce any inobvious behaviour which can influence the
>   function and the result usage and be probably considered undesirable?

No, not that I know of.

> Are there any better practices for the issue?

If possible, try to eliminate the use of array altogether, unless of course the performance is paramount.

Answer (score 4):

The only possibly non-obvious thing I can think of is that `array.toIndexedSeq` doesn't create a simple wrapper over the array itself like Java's `Collections.unmodifiable*` methods do, but copies the elements into a new collection. (Otherwise later changes in the array could cause the "immutable" sequence to suddenly mutate.)

Comment: The non-obvious being Java's behavior, of course. :-) Well, Java returns a "read only" version, not an immutable one.

Comment: What's the difference between "read only" and immutable, @daniel-c-sobral?

Comment: @Ivan, immutable collections do not support mutation. Read-only collections on the other hand are just unmodifiable views of mutable collections. See line#1014 onwards [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html).